# Font rendering differences Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: debian-jessie, font

I'm having some trouble generating PDF files with **unoconv** on a Debian (Jessie) server. I use ODT templates in order to generate my final PDF.

Everything is working great on my local machine (Ubuntu 14.04) but when I use the same process on the server, the font is rendered differently for the document.

I tried to modify the font used for the templates with the Google Arimo font, which is supposed to be "cross-platform", but still the same problem.
I also tried to install Infinality on my server but nothing changed.

As I am quite a newbie to both Linux systems and server administration I would gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are the desired fonts installed?

Comment: Am pretty sure I successfully installed Arimo but I have no idea how to check if that's true.

Comment: Did you restart the font server? E.g. `service xfstt restart`

Comment: I only relaoded the font cache but did not restart the font server.